# Mapping diagonal elements recursively and check for condition, Python

Tags: python

Given a list of speaking sessions, represented by a list, where each element is a list holding the start time, end time and speaker name such as:

```
a = [ [  265,  604, "S1" ],
      [  604, 2373, "S1" ],
      [ 2373, 3719, "S1" ],
      [ 3719, 4910, "S2" ],
      [ 4910, 6790, "S2" ] ]
```

I wish to reduce it into a new list where consecutive sessions should be merge.

A merge is combining the first start time of a session and the end time of the consecutive session, i.e.:

```
[a[i][0], a[i+1][1], a[i][2]]
```

A merge can be performed if the speaker of consecutive sessions is the same, and the break between sessions is not too long, i.e.

```
 a[i+1][0] - a[i][1] < 1000  and  a[i][2] == a[i+1][2]
```

If the resulting list can be further merged, it should be merged too.

So for the example above the result should be:

```
[ [265, 3719, 'S1'], [3719, 6790, 'S2'] ].
```

---

I am iterating the list using the condition mentioned above, but for some reason, I am getting stuck with only the first 2 group of elements.

Comment: Why do you think you need recursion for this?

Comment: Apologies for using the actual condition,The list was much bigger than this with lot of other info, for ease of use, I removed the irrelevant data. I don't necessarily need to do it with recursion, I was simply using the for loop with if conditions but didn't get the necessary output

Comment: the format is  [ [265, 3719, 'S1'] where 265 is start time and 3719 is end time. The actual idea is to combine the start and end time for a particular speaker. so that's why 265 to 3719 is the ideal output for S1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is to find the start and end of the groupings:

```
def grps(a):
    it = iter(a)
    i = next(it)
    start, spk = i[0], i[2]
    for ele in it:
        if spk != ele[2]:
            yield [start, ele[0], spk]
            spk = ele[2]
            start = ele[0]
    yield start, ele[1], spk


print(list(grps(a)))
```

Which would give  you:

```
[[265, 3719, 'S1'], [3719, 6790, 'S2']]
```

When you encounter a new speaker, their start time is the last speakers end time, you only update the start variable each time you encounter a new speaker so you always output the begin and end time for each speaker, the last speaker we yield outside the loop using their own second element to get their end time.

Another way if the next speaker did not contain the end time i.e there was a gap  would be to use the previous element:

```
def grps(a):
    it = iter(a)
    prev = next(it)
    start, spk = prev[0], prev[2]
    for ele in it:
        if spk != ele[2]:
            yield [start, prev[1], spk]
            start = ele[0]
            spk = ele[2]
        prev = ele
    yield start, ele[1], spk
```

But in your case that is not needed once the format is the same as posted.

Or using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


def gps(a):
    for k, v in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(2)):
        v = list(v)
        yield [v[0][0],  v[-1][1], v[0][2]]


print(list(gps(a)))
```

Output:

```
[[265, 3719, 'S1'], [3719, 6790, 'S2']]
```

Or a slight variation if you just want to pull the first and last without calling list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import deque


def gps(a):
    for k, v in groupby(a, key=itemgetter(2)):
        start, end = next(v), deque(v, maxlen=1).pop()
        yield [start[0],  end[1], end[2]]
```

If you data happened to be unordered you could use a dict:

```
def gps(a):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: {"mn":float("inf"),"mx":float("-inf")})
    for sub in a:
        key = sub[-1]
        if d[key]["mn"] > sub[0]:
            d[key]["mn"] = sub[0]
        elif d[key]["mx"] < sub[1]:
            d[key]["mx"]  = sub[1]
    return d

for k,v in gps(a).items():
    print([v["mn"], v["mx"], k])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the flow. In,fact I was just about to comment that the reason I was checking a difference of 1000 was the new speakers start time might not be the same as last speakers end time.

Comment: @AyushChordia, no worries,  the second  and third examples will handle that, by using the last value in the current speakers chain using the prev logic we will always pull that speakers final time.

Comment: It doesn't work for this data, I guess the difference condition of 1000 is not accounted: Try for this data:[ [ 493, 2244, "S1" ], [ 4741, 6526, "S1" ], [ 6526, 7729, "S1" ], [ 7729, 9476, "S1" ], [ 0, 493, "S0" ], [ 2244, 3521, "S4" ], [ 3521, 4716, "S4" ] ]

The output should be: [[493,2244,"S1"], [4741,9476, "S1"], [0,493, "S0], [2244, 4716, "S4"]

Answer (score 1):

Derived from Padraic's answer, more readable in my opinion, and addresses the 1000 difference:

```
def nextSpeech(segments):
    it = iter(segments)
    start = end = next(it)
    def isSameSpeech(element): return element[2] == start[2] and end[0] - start[1] < 1000
    def getSpeech(): return start[0], end[1], end[2]

    for element in it:
        if isSameSpeech(element):
            end = element
        else:
            yield getSpeech()
            start = end = element
    yield getSpeech()

list(nextSpeech(a))
```

And you get:

```
[(265, 3719, 'S1'), (3719, 6790, 'S2')]
```

If the input segments aren't sorted, you can either run `list(nextSpeech(sorted(a)))` or modify the function's first two lines to sort the input by default with the 'sort' argument:

```
def nextSpeech(segments, sort=True):
    it = iter(sorted(segments) if sort else segments)
    ...
```

Note that `sorted()` can be replaced by any other sorting function (or lambda) to your liking.

Comment: There is an error in the code. Only captures two elements. Try for this data:[
        [
            493,
            2244,
            "S1"
        ],
        [
            4741,
            6526,
            "S1"
        ],
        [
            6526,
            7729,
            "S1"
        ],
        [
            7729,
            9476,
            "S1"
        ],
        [
            0,
            493,
            "S0"
        ],
        [
            2244,
            3521,
            "S4"
        ],
        [
            3521,
            4716,
            "S4"
        ]
    ]

Comment: You didn't mention the input wasn't sorted.
You could simply run:
`list(nextSpeech(sorted(a)))`

Or have it sorted to your liking and then run:
`list(nextSpeech(mysort(a)))`
Please consider accepting my answer if it works. :)

Comment: I also edited my answer with this solution and another one by modifying the function.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find the (indexes for) breaks between the sessions:

```
breaks = [i + 1 
          for (i, (a0, a1)) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:]))
          if (a1[0] - a0[1]) >= 1000 or (a0[2] != a1[2])]
```

and then to find sessions to merge:

```
sessions = zip([0] + breaks, b + [len(breaks)-1])
```

and thus the answer is:

```
answer = [[a[start][0], a[end][1], a[start][2]] 
          for (start, end) in sessions]
```

---

We can do without the indexes:

```
 breaks = [b for b in zip(a, a[1:])
           if (a1[0] - a0[1]) >= 1000 or (a0[2] != a1[2])]
 sessions = zip([(None, a[0])] + breaks, 
                 breaks + [(a[-1], None)])
 answer = [[p[1][0], n[0][1], p[1][2]] 
           for (p,n) in sessions]
```